# Boostrap Col Not Working Sm

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up some social media icons, and it works well except for the fact that the Facebook one isn't working well with columns.

When it's a small screen they should all have 2 columns, however Facebook's icon is still taking 12.

My code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:center;"></i></a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-2"  style="text-align:center;"></i></a>

<a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-2"  style="text-align:center;"></i></a>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-2"  style="text-align:center;"></i></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x col-xs-0 col-sm-2 col-md-2"  style="text-align:center;"></i></a>
```

What my icons look on a "small" screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change col-xs-12 for col-xs-0. You have a grid of 12 colums.

I think It's a error with copy and paste. :)

Comment: That's it!  Thanks so much!  I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook is taking 12 because of the `col-xs-12` class that you gave to it.

However, I strongly recommend to use the bootstrap grid properly, wrapping elements into columns and columns into rows, for example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- You element(s) -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <!-- You element(s) -->
  </div>
  <!-- and so on ... -->
</div>
```

Edit the column classes (`col-md-2` in my example) with your needs.

Also you can use `text-center` class instead of `style="text-align:center;"`

I suggest to read the [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) documentation